# Logo position does not change in MyBB

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo, mybb

I have been trying to change my logo position of myBB forum using a custom theme.

It's been changing position sometimes hours or days after I changed it and it's really confusing me.

Here is my Code :

```
<div class="topwrap"><div class="wrap"><div style="float: right;">{$welcomeblock}</div>
<span id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu clearfixspec">
                 <ul>
                <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php">Forums</a>
<li><a href="search.php?action=finduserthreads&uid={$mybb->user['uid']}">Your Threads</a></li>
<li><a href="search.php?action=finduser&uid={$mybb->user['uid']}">Your Posts</a></li>
<li><a href="http://myforum.net/forum/private.php">PM</a></li>
<li><a href="http://myforum.net/forum/usercp.php">UserCP</a></li>
</ul></li>


</div></div>
<div id="headerwrap">
<div class="logo"
<a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php"><img src="{$theme['logo']}"alt="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" align="right" title="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" /></a></div>


</div>
</div></div>
<div id="container">
        <a name="top" id="top"></a>
  <div id="news_thicker">
                    <div class="news_content">                    
                    <img src="images/announce.png" style="padding-right: 5px;float: left;margin-top: -4px;"></img>   <span class="title">Announcements :</span>                    
                    <ol id="news">  
      <li><a href="#">Forum is still being developed, please report any bugs to XBatt</a></li>
  </ol>
</div></div><br />
        <hr class="hidden" />
        <br class="clear" />
        <div id="content">
        {$pm_notice}
            {$bannedwarning}
            {$bbclosedwarning}
            {$unreadreports}
            {$pending_joinrequests}
            <navigation>
            <br />
```

Part of global.css showing logo details

```
.logo {
        background: none;
        position: absolute;
        width:500px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: -10px;
}

.logo:hover {
       opacity: 0.8;
       padding-left: 5px;
}
```

How can i do this ?

EDIT - I also use CloudFlare, I have tried purging the cache still nothing. I have temporarily disabled it till I get this fixed as well.

Answer (score 1):

your code is missing a `>` look here on  `<div class="logo"`:

```
<div class="logo"
<a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php"><img src="{$theme['logo']}"alt="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" align="right" title="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" /></a></div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not only your browser's cache causing the delay in actually seeing the change online, but mybb also has it's own default cache that it goes to first for theme css. You'll have to change your files in cache>themes> theme1, theme2, theme3. In some of the older versions of mybb, there's only theme 1 and 2. And for some reason, the changes may still take a while to show up onscreen.